# Using Qwt on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qwt

How can I compile and run [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) programs using [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) on Mac OS X?

I always get an error telling me that it can't find `libqwt.dylib`. For what I have understood from my googling it won't help to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `environment.plist` since Apple has disabled that due to security reasons so how am I supposed to do it (without manually copying the lib to my .app for every recompile)?

I have tried both `qmake -spec macx-g++` and `qmake` without any spec. The lib is in `/usr/local/qwt/lib` at the moment. Should I move it to some system path manually or is there a better way to do it (by using otool and install_name_tool magics)?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's bad idea to edit environment.plist or in any other way to change your profile settings to add such "non-standard" path to it.

I assumed you have something like this in you project *.pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-5.2.0/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-5.2.0/lib \
    -lqwt
```

Or you try to run one of samples where all this additional path are included by:

```
include( ../examples.pri )
```

Anyway you get this message at program start:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libqwt.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/kemiisto/Downloads/qwt-5.2.0/examples/histogram/histogram.app/Contents/MacOS/histogram
Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

---

Well, you can use **solution** from [this](http://renderfast.com/2008/06/27/using-dynamic-libraries-in-mac-os-x/) blog post. I have tested it with Qt 4.6 and Qwt 5.2. It works.

After running `qmake -spec macx-g++` in qwt sources distribution directory (already done by you), edit src/Makefile. Find the string with

```
-install_name libqwt.5.dylib
```

and make it looks like this (change to full path)

```
-install_name /usr/local/qwt-5.2.0/lib/libqwt.dylib
```

Now (re)build Qwt (make clean && make) and reinstall it (sudo make install).